# How to fix regarding connection between Android and MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database-connection

i'm kind a new to Android, MySQL and PHP. I'm having problem with my project in register page. When i input name and ID value and hit save button, my data is in mysql database, but when i fill the same name and password again and hit save, it's says Data saved to server, instead of error -> if (res.equals("1")) error.setText("Error"). Is anybody got any clue? Thanks.

Here's my code:

register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="311dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

<TextView
android:text="Registration"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="25dp"
/>


<TextView
android:text=""
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="20dp"
/>

<TableRow android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TextView
android:text="Name :"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15dp"
/>


<EditText android:id="@+id/edtname" 
android:maxWidth="180sp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
</EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<TextView
android:text="ID no :"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15dp"
/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edtid" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:inputType="textPassword">
</EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>


</TableRow>

<TextView
android:text=""
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="20dp"
/>

<TableRow 
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<Button android:text="SAVE" 
android:id="@+id/btnsave" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:onClick="next" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button android:text="BACK" 
android:id="@+id/btnback" 
android:onClick="back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

</TableRow>

<TextView
android:text=""
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="20dp"
/>

<TextView
android:text=""
android:id="@+id/error"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
android:textSize="20dp"
/>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Register.java

```
package com.example.m_vote;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Register extends Activity {

EditText nm,id;
TextView error;
Button save,back;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    nm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtname);
    id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtid);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override

            public void onClick(View v){

         //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nm.getText().toString()));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id.getText().toString()));


/* String valid = "1";*/      

        String response = null;

        try {

           response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/appmysql/data.php", postParameters);

           String res = response.toString();

           res = res.trim();

           res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

           error.setText(res);

           if (res.equals("1")) error.setText("Error");

           else 
               {
               error.setText("Registration complete! "); 
               }

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

           id.setText(e.toString());
        }
        }

  });
 }

 public void back (View theButton)
 {
    Intent a = new Intent (this,Mainmenu.class);
    startActivity(a);
 }
 }
```

CustomHttpClient.java

```
package com.example.m_vote;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class CustomHttpClient {
/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
 *
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

data.php

```
<?php
$nm=$_POST['name'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("projek1");

$query = "INSERT INTO user (ID,name) values ('$id','$nm')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("REPORTGagal Query Simpan KRS.");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){

    echo 1;
 }
else {

    // print status message
   echo 0;
 }


?>
```

Comment: Check the `Database` columns any of them will `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`

Comment: please post your sql query

Comment: Mysql  database:

create table user
{
id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY('name')
}

Comment: What is in your `user` table after you try to insert the same data more than once? Do all the rows you attempted to insert actually appear?

Comment: For example i insert name 'aa' and id '11' , and i insert the same data again, it only appear 1 row of 'aa' '11'. But i still get 'data saved to server' instead of 'error'